# Como usar print con un loop FOR y arreglos en Python

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy apenas aprendiendo Python. Hice un pequeño código con ciclo FOR y arreglos donde pido que indiquen la cantidad de nombres de gatos a capturar y sus nombres y después imprimir sus nombres.
El código es:

```
res=input('Escribe cuántos nombres capturarás: ')

j=1

nom=[]

for i in range(int(res)):

    print('Nombre del gato '+str(j)+': ', end='')
    nom.append(input())
    j+=1
else:
    print('¡Has terminado de capturar!\n')

for i in nom:
    print('Los nombres de tus gatos son: '+ str(i), sep='')

print('\n')

print(nom)

print(nom[0])

print(nom[1])

print('Los nombres de tus gatos son: ', (*nom), sep=' y ')
```

y esta es su salida; probando varias formas de print() queda:

```
Escribe cuántos nombres capturarás: 2
Nombre del gato 1: pelos
Nombre del gato 2: rulas
¡Has terminado de capturar!

Los nombres de tus gatos son: pelos
Los nombres de tus gatos son: rulas


['pelos', 'rulas']
pelos
rulas
Los nombres de tus gatos son:  y pelos y rulas
```

Quiero imprimir el resultado del arreglo para que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
Los nombres de tus gatos son:  pelos y rulas
```

Saludos a todos.

Answer (score 0):

puede hacerlo asi:

```
res=input('Escribe cuántos nombres capturarás: ')

j=1

nom=[]
# definimos resultado 
resultado = "Los nombres de tus gatos son: "

for i in range(int(res)):

    print('Nombre del gato '+str(j)+': ', end='')
    nom.append(input())
    j+=1
else:
    print('¡Has terminado de capturar!\n')

# la funcion enumerate enumera los datos de un areglo
# por clave valor

for k,v in enumerate(nom):
    '''
     hacemos un condicional de que k sea diferente
     de la longitud del arreglo para validar que sea el ultimo elemento y no agregar
     "y" al final
    '''
    y = ' y ' if (len(nom)-1 != k ) else ''
    resultado += str(v) +y

print(resultado)
print('\n')

print(nom)

print(nom[0])

print(nom[1])

print('Los nombres de tus gatos son: ', (*nom), sep=' y ')
```

Comment: Gracias por la idea pero al hacerlo así, la salida es: Los nombres de tus gatos son: 1 y 1

Comment: Sorry era v no i xD

Answer (score 0):

Si no lo entendí mal, el problema se resume en:

- Tenemos una lista con dos (o más?) elementos y queremos emitir un mensaje en el que se muestren los nombres de esos elementos separados por "y"

Hay varias formas de intentar esto:

### Usando el parámetro `sep` de `print()`

Esto es más o menos lo que tú intentaste. Tú hiciste:

```
print('Los nombres de tus gatos son: ', (*nom), sep=' y ')
```

pero no funcionó como esperabas, ya que el separador se aplica a todos los argumentos de `print()`, incluyendo el mensaje inicial "Los nombres de tus gatos...", por lo que sale un "y" de más.

Basta separarlo en dos `print()`, uno para el mensaje inicial y otro para la lista de nombres:

```
print("Los nombres de tus gatos son:", end=" ")
print(*nom, sep=" y ")
```

En el primer print hago uso del parámetro `end` para que en lugar de un retorno de carro (que es lo que usa por defecto) use un espacio, y así salga el siguiente `print()` en la misma línea.

He empezado por esta solución por ser la que tú has intentado, pero no me parece la mejor. Hace uso del operador *splat*, que es el poner un asterisco delante de `nom` para así "desempaquetar" esa lista y convertirla en una serie de argumentos. Es decir, el segundo `print()` es equivalente a:

```
print(nom[0], nom[1], sep=" y ")
```

El uso del *splat* es un tanto avanzado y no lo veo necesario en este caso.

### Usando el operador `.join()` de las cadenas

Esta es la forma más habitual de juntar una serie de cadenas en una sola, usando el separador que quieras:

```
" y ".join(nom)
```

El resultado de lo anterior es otra cadena que ya puedes imprimir con un `print()` normal, o si prefieres guardarlo en otra variable, o retornarlo como resultado, o lo que sea necesario. En tu caso:

```
print("Los nombres de tus gatos son: ", " y ".join(nom))
```

### Mediante bucles

Puedes hacer un bucle que imprima uno a uno cada elemento de la lista, poniendo un `" y "` a continuación, salvo para el último para el que no se pondría ese `" y "`.

Personalmente prefiero la solución con `str.join()`, pero te muestro también cómo se haría con el bucle, puesto que es lo que pides en el título de la pregunta.

```
print("Los nombres de tus gatos son:", end=" ")
for i, nombre in enumerate(nom):
   if i<len(nom)-1: # Si no es el último
      print(nombre, end=" y ")
   else:
      print(nombre)  # Si es el último
```

#### Y si son más de dos?

Cualquiera de los ejemplos anteriores funciona con cualquier número de elementos, pero en mi opinión no quedaría muy bien su salida, pues sería algo como:

```
"Tus gatos se llaman: Mizifú y Zapirón y Mr. Jinks y Tom y Nyan y Maru"
```

La separación reiterada con "y" no queda bien.

No sería muy difícil modificar la solución de `.join()` o la del bucle para que use comas para separar los elementos, salvo el último que separaría con `"y"`. Te dejo que lo intentes.

Comment: Genial, agradezco mucho tu ayuda. De hecho, me funcionaron todas las soluciones que explicas. Pero la de .join me parece muy buena. Gracias de nuevo!!!!

Comment: Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada para señalar a otros que ha resuelto tu problema.